# Deserialization does not seem to work with strongly named objects in the IDE

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

Situation:

I have a bunch of business objects sitting behind a web service.  All the objects are encapsulated in a BusObjects.DLL, which is strongly named and sits in the GAC on the server (because other apps on the server access it as well).

I have a click-once client app, which calls the said web service.  The click-once app also ships with this BusObjects.DLL.

The way the web service returns data to the client is as follows:  It serializes the business object down to a byte array and returns this byte array to the client.  The client deserializes the received byte array back into a business object.  This is possible because both the client and the server code have a reference to the same BusObjects.DLL.  This all works great.

The problem for me is this.  When I have the client solution (which includes the BusObjects project) in the VS2005 IDE, the code is unable to deserialize the byte array back into a business object because, it claims,

> "Could not load file or assembly
>   'CC.BusObjects,
>   Version=2.12.1.47, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=af56fdb58c626305' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located
>   assembly's manifest definition does
>   not match the assembly reference.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

I've tried matching versions, but nothing seems to work if the BusObjects project is being referenced as a project, rather than an outside assembly.  Unfortunately, I have to have the BusObjects inside the solution for debugging.

What can I do to fix this issue?  I've heard of version redirection, but can't seem to make it work with a strong named assembly, but perhaps I am doing it wrong.

Here is the serialization and deserialization code:

```
    public static byte[] ToBinary(Object objToBinary)
    {
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter(null, 
                  new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.Clone));
        formatter.Serialize(memStream, objToBinary);
        memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return memStream.ToArray();
    }


    public static object BinaryTo(byte[] objFromBinary)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(objFromBinary);
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        ms.Position = 0;
        object obj = formatter.Deserialize(ms);
        return obj;
    }
```

To serialize:

```
[WebMethod]
public byte [] GetContacts()
{
   return ToBinary(BusObjects.GetContacts());
}
```

To deserialize:

```
byte [] bts = ContactService.GetContacts();
List<Contact> lstContacts = (List<Contact>) BinaryTo(bts);
```

Comment: Are you signing the assembly on the client side as well?  That is in your client project, if you go to properties->signing, do you have the same key that the server side uses to sign your assembly?

Comment: Well, it's the same project, so yes, it's signed the same way.

Comment: JP, your initial hunch was right on the money.  I went and asked the guys that do all our builds...and it turns out that they are not using the key I provided them, but their own key, for security reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's almost certainly happening is you have the version number set to be auto-incrementing during the build process.  This often results in one off version number scenarios that can cause load issues like you are seeing.

Try the following

- Go to Solution explorer.
- Expand the Properties Node
- Open AssemblyInfo.cs
- Change the AssemblyVersion attribute to have a hard coded version number